# Angular - Access Sass variable in a controller?

Tags: angularjs, sass

Is it possible to access a SASS variable in an Angular controller?

At the moment I'm creating a bar chart and I have the colors in an array e.g.

```
var barColors = ['#fff', '#e32dsa'];
```

Would be nice if there's a way so i can ensure code is easier to maintain.

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting question. I saw this https://viget.com/extend/sharing-data-between-sass-and-javascript-with-json but it seems to work only for backend code (uses *require*). Not sure how it would work with frontend/AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with [sass-extract](https://github.com/jgranstrom/sass-extract) which also includes native support for sass maps, arrays, @imports and so on.

Either use it on the server and include the JSON result in the response to the client, or use [sass-extract-loader](https://github.com/jgranstrom/sass-extract) with webpack to simply require the sass file in your controller.

*in your style.scss file*

```
$barColors: #fff #e32dsa;
```

*in your controller.js*

```
const style = require('sass-extract-loader!./path/to/styles.scss');
const $barColors = style.global.$barColors.value;

console.log($barColors[0].value.hex)); // '#ffffff'
console.log($barColors[1].value.hex)); // '#e32dsa'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try moving to [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/docs/using-loaders.html)(a module loader that also does a bunch of other fancy stuff like requiring in sass) and pulling in this loader https://github.com/buildo/sass-variables-loader